# Redirect all front end traffic to one page, but allow admin panel access - Magento 1.9

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, magento-1.9

How do I allow staff to access the admin panel on my Magento 1.9 with redirect all other front-end traffic to a single holding page?

I got the front end redirect to work fine, but for the back end (line 3 and 4 below) I tried this but it isn't working (still redirects me to `index.html`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.html$ 
RewriteRule $ /index.html [R=302,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin_xaa/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php)?/admin_xaa(/|$)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your htaccess file in your question, could you please do let us know which url you are hitting which takes you to index.html file?

Comment: The issue most likely is a simple one: the first redirection rule _always_ matches, also for attempted requests to the admin section. Keep in mind that rewriting rules are processed from top to bottom. Your admin related rules never apply since they are never reached.